# plot two x axis on one ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am trying to add a second x axis to my plot using the following data:

```
 depth     s.den    c.den      bd      car  X  min
1      1 0.3023393 2.859395 0.05735 35.74244  0 2017
2      2 0.3055764 3.373670 0.07015 42.17087  1 1987
3      3 0.3367664 4.629492 0.09165 42.08629  2 1954
4      4 0.3318848 3.789447 0.07765 37.89447  3 1941
5      5 0.3178764 3.432860 0.07075 31.20782  4 1920
6      6 0.2401508 2.808528 0.06045 28.08528  5 1909
7      7 0.3044616 2.480078 0.05715 22.54617  6 1889
8      8 0.4002132 3.250899 0.06770 32.50899  7 1878
9      9 0.4551193 2.901270 0.05735 29.01270  8 1860
```

I am looking to plot depth and min on opposing x axis, and car on the y axis.
this is the code I an currently using. I would like to have depth on the bottom x axis and min on the top. Any help is appreciated.

```
CAR <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = LHB, mapping = aes(x = depth, y = car), col = 'black') +
  ggtitle("CARLHB") +
  xlab("Depth (cm)") +
  ylab(bquote(Carbon~Accumulation~(g~C/m^2/yr^-1))) 
CAR
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT #2: I think the OP just wants a secondary axis that has labels from the `min` column. Since this is a single, sorted series, we can use the same breaks as the primary axis but with different labels. Much simpler than what I suggested earlier.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = LHB, aes(x = depth, y = car), col = 'black') +
  labs(title = "CARLHB", x = "Depth (cm)",
       y = bquote(Carbon~Accumulation~(g~C/m^2/yr^-1))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:9, minor_breaks = NULL,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(identity, breaks = 1:9, labels = LHB$min))
```

[image]

---

`ggplot2` is an opinionated framework, and one of the more controversial opinions is that it discourages secondary axes. See here for some arguments against secondary axes, which Hadley Wickham (creator of ggplot2) has also espoused: https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/

Secondary axes in ggplot2 are really just axis decorations; you still have to manually transform your data to fit the primary axis, and then show the inverse transformation for the secondary axis breaks. We might do that here with the code below.

Note that the `min` years are transformed to fit on the `depth` scale, and then we can use `sec_axis` with the inverse calculation to make the axis text work.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = LHB, aes(x = depth, y = car), col = 'black') +
  geom_line(data = LHB, aes(x = (min-1850)/20, y = car), col = 'gray60') +
  labs(title = "CARLHB", x = "Depth (cm)",
       y = bquote(Carbon~Accumulation~(g~C/m^2/yr^-1))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:9, minor_breaks = NULL,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~(.*20)+1850,
                                         breaks = seq(1850, 2040, by = 20)))
```

[image]

---

Edit: it's also possible you just want to note the years along the top. We could skip axis labels and just plot the text:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = LHB, aes(x = depth, y = car), col = 'black') +
  geom_text(data = LHB, aes(x = depth, y = Inf, label = min), vjust = -0.3) +
  # geom_line(data = LHB, aes(x = (min-1850)/20, y = car), col = 'gray60') +
  labs(title = "CARLHB\n", x = "Depth (cm)",
       y = bquote(Carbon~Accumulation~(g~C/m^2/yr^-1))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:9, minor_breaks = NULL) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, it was not about plotting the line but more so to show the age where the depth is when looking at changes in CAR on the graph. so it would begin at 1,2,3..300 on the bottom, but 2021,2020,2019...-2500 on top if that makes sense

Comment: Please explain more. What do you mean 1,2,3...300 when the example only goes to 9? What do you mean 2021,2020-2500 when the example varies from 1860 to 2017? Does increasing depth always mean decreasing `min` with a linear relationship?

Comment: Sorry, the example i have given is only 1:9 but it is taken from a larger dataset (1:300) as i did not want to put the entire thing into here as it would take up a lot of space. Increasing depth does always mean a decrease in min yes.

Comment: Can you help me understand what you're looking for that's different from the top and bottom approaches I suggested? It sounds like you want 1 to align with 2021 but it doesn't in your data (depth 1 is 2017). And I don't see a linear relationship that would make them align (depth 1-2 changes -30 yrs, depth 2-3 changes -33 yrs)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidypaleo)

model <- age_depth_model(
  depth = cars$min,
  age = cars$depth
)



ggplot(cars, aes(x = depth, y = car)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_age_depth(model, depth_name = "min") +
  ggtitle("CARLHB") +
  xlab("Depth (cm)") +
  geom_point() +
  ylab(bquote(Carbon~Accumulation~(g~C/m^2/yr^-1)))
```

[image]
hope that works !

Comment: Thanks for that, when i try to run the model i get the following error ``Error in adm$trans_factories[[x$trans]](adm$data[[x$cols[1]]], adm$data[[x$cols[2]]]) : 
  Non-finite values in transformation```` is this something you've come across?